# String comparison in R

Tags: r

I am trying to compare two string in R. Please advise how to compare n and reversed_split in the below R code.

```
n= readLines(file("stdin"))
string <- strsplit(as.character(n), "")
string = unlist(string)
reversed_split = string[nchar(n):1]

if(string == reversed_split)
 print("Indeed")
else
 print("Not At All")
```

Comment: can you please share your question with some example....

Comment: `if(all(string == reversed_split))`. And you need to open and close `{`, `}` in the `if`statement. Also, use `n <- readline()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare 2 vectors within `if()` statement. `if()` accepts a single `TRUE` or `FALSE` condition. You can add `all()` function and it will work:

```
n <- c("madam" )
string <- strsplit(as.character(n), "")
string = unlist(string)
reversed_split = string[nchar(n):1]

if (all(string == reversed_split) )  print("Indeed") else print("Not At All")
```

Here is the output:

```
> if (all(string == reversed_split) )  print("Indeed") else print("Not At All")
[1] "Indeed"
```

You might find useful to use library `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
stri_reverse("madam")
## [1] "madam"
stri_reverse("sir")
## [1] "ris"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`identitcal`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/identical.html) function from [`base`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/00Index.html) package to help you compare character vectors, which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` able to be used in conditional statements:

```
ifelse(identical(c("a", "s"), c("a", "s")), "Indeed", "Not At All")
# Your question could be solved as:
ifelse(identical(string, reversed_split), "Indeed", "Not At All")
```